# Minimum Radius of Curvature an Optical Fiber can be bent

Tags: optics, visible-light, reflection, refraction

Using the thickness and refractive index of an optical fiber, is it possible to know the maximum radius of curvature it can be bent before there are losses due to refraction?

In my research, I came across a concept called the critical angle, above which total internal reflection occurs, which is the principle optical fibers work on. The Critical angle formula is given by arcsin(n2/n1), and below this I understand losses will start to occur due to refraction. Is there any possible formula to calculate which exact radius of curvature the fiber can be bent?